# Does anyone recognize the line element $ds^2 = ( 1 - \frac{2m}{r} )dt^2 + 2 dt dr$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

I've stumbled upon the line element $ds^2 = ( 1 - \frac{2m}{r} )dt^2 + 2 dt dr$. Obviously the corresponding metric tensor has components:

$\begin{bmatrix} g_{tt} & g_{tr} \\ g_{rt} & g_{rr} \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 - \frac{2m}{r} & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

I found it in a practice problem. The problem asks to find the null geodesics, but I've already done that and that's not why I'm here. I'm just curious as to what kind of a system this would describe - It's not often that I see a metric tensor with off-diagonal components.

Does anyone recognize this line element? If so, what kind of a system does it describe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Eddington-Finkelstein metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates) in the case where $d\phi = d\theta = 0$ i.e. a radial trajectory. The $t$ coordinate is actually the Eddington-Finkelstein $u$ coordinate.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Greg.Paul: if the answer is satisfactory please click on the tick symbol to accept it. That marks the question as answered (and gives me 15 rep points :-).